# Flutter: do not open ExpansionTile

Tags: flutter

Before open this widget I need to validate other parameters for the user. So if the user clicks to soon I'll display a SnackBar saying "You forgot to do something first".

I can wrap the children inside this widget in a `Visibility` widget but the status would be open anyway.

Can I validate somehow this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve but it seems like it would be better achieved using FutureBuilder or StreamBuilder. You'd definitely want to learn state management as well to get a better understanding about Streams: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

Comment: No, that's not what I need. The user only needs to fill an input before clicking the ExpansionTile. If he clicks on this before filling up the input the status of the ExpansionTile should be FALSE always

Answer (score 0):

*I think you want to validate some fields, before opening the expansion tile.*

You can use a `boolean` variable for that, first set the `bool` variable to `false` and after that `validate` your `fields` on the `onExpansionChanged` method and show the `toast`.

Assign a bool field, When your fields are validated then change that `bool` field to `true` ,

Let the `bool` field be `false` by default and then use it to hide the expansion tile `childrens` if `false`, and show the `childrens` if set to `true`.

```
  bool isValid = false;

ExpansionTile(
            onExpansionChanged: (value){
              if(isValid){
                print(" ok");
              }else{
                print("Show a toast, Please check all Fields");
              }
            },
                title: Text(
                  'Title',
                ),
                children: <Widget>[
                  isValid ? ListTile(
                    title: Text('data'),
                  ) : new Container(),
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: yeah but that's what I mean, I can make the children widgets visible or not but that's not a proper solution since I can still change the value of the expansionTitle. If we have nothing inside of it and the status is true for the user will be no difference, ok, but I have to apply another layer of complexity here. I'm more worried to have have always a false value when I click the ExpansionTitle that the children widgets visibility

Comment: @Dani you can change the false value to true in your condition method, that's it.

Comment: that doesn't fix the main problem: the state of the expansionTile which is what I don't want to change. That "value" changes everything you click on the expansionTile and that's what I need to check before update it, not whatever I do inside of it